# if textbox has string then show msgbox but the (.) doesnt count. visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i have this textbox where i want to input only number the (.) included. for example is 190.5.

but if it has text for example 190.5g then it will show msgbox("error")

i have this code i found somewhere

```
 Dim allDigit = pbox.Text.Trim.Length <> 0 AndAlso _
      pbox.Text.All(Function(chr) Char.IsDigit(chr))
        If Not allDigit Then
            MsgBox("Please input number only on price")
            pbox.Clear()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

if i add . on the number it shows the msgbox so is there anyway to include the . ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx), rather than pulling the string apart yourself.

```
Dim value As Decimal
Dim yourString As String = "1234"
If Not Decimal.TryParse(yourString, value) Then
    MsgBox("Please input number only on price")
    pbox.Clear()
    Exit Sub
End If
```

It should be noted that the character that represents the decimal separator will vary depending on the language settings of the OS - for American / British English it'll be period, for German it'll be comma.

Comment: i have no idea how to use that. i just got the code from somewhere so i dont know how that works.

Comment: @BillyOtsuka - have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function instead

```
    If Not IsNumeric(pbox.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please input number only on price")
        pbox.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in c# which i use

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
            && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
                            //message box
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' 
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
                            //message box
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```